# UiComponent export button issue, error: getRowData() must be an instance of Magento\Framework\Api\Search\DocumentInterface (Solved by myself)

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, uicomponent, magento-2.1.9, ui-grid

I am using Ui-Component for export button for export grid column with below code:

```
<exportButton name="export_button" />
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="selectProvider" xsi:type="string">test_listing.test_listing.test_columns.ids</item>
        </item>
     </argument>
</exportButton>
```

**Anyone have faced this kind of issue...** 
Please let me know if i need to post my Dataprovider class

**My collection file is below:**

```
class Collection extends TestCollection implements SearchResultInterface
{
     /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getAggregations()
    {
        return $this->aggregations;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function setAggregations($aggregations)
    {
        $this->aggregations = $aggregations;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getSearchCriteria()
    {
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function setSearchCriteria(\Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaInterface $searchCriteria = null)
    {
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getTotalCount()
    {
        return $this->getSize();
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function setTotalCount($totalCount)
    {
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function setItems(array $items = null)
    {
        return $this;
    }
}
```

> Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to
>   Magento\Ui\Model\Export\MetadataProvider::getRowData() must be an
>   instance of Magento\Framework\Api\Search\DocumentInterface,
>   instance of Package\Module\Model\Test given, called in
>   /home/ashish/magentoPro/vendor/magento/module-ui/Model/Export/ConvertToCsv.php
>   on line 84 and defined in
>   /home/ashish/magentoPro/vendor/magento/module-ui/Model/Export/MetadataProvider.php:147 ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**I have resolved the issue** by adding below code

```
$this->_init(
      'Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\Document', 'Package\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Test'
            );
```

to my Grid Collection file(**path:Package\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Test\Grid\Collection**):

**Full Code:**

```
    class Collection extends TestCollection implements SearchResultInterface
    {
        /**
         * Define model & resource model
         */
         protected function _construct() {
             $this->_init(
                        'Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\Document', 'Package\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Test'
             );
         }
     /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getAggregations()
    {
        return $this->aggregations;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function setAggregations($aggregations)
    {
        $this->aggregations = $aggregations;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getSearchCriteria()
    {
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function setSearchCriteria(\Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaInterface $searchCriteria = null)
    {
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getTotalCount()
    {
        return $this->getSize();
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function setTotalCount($totalCount)
    {
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function setItems(array $items = null)
    {
        return $this;
    }
}
```

As the error was indicating I need to pass **`Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\Document`** as a model for the Grid document for **`getItems() abstarct function`** of **`SearchResultInterface`**
So that the Grid export default functionality can work and it is working like charm.

Anyone facing this kind of issue can let me know I will share my experience.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks, worked for me! To clarify it should be added here: Package\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Test\Grid

Comment: I have tried to implement export option in the product grid. When try to enable the export button from product_listing.xml, I'm facing the following issue while export Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Magento\Ui\Model\Export\ConvertToXml::getRowData() must be an instance of Magento\Framework\Api\Search\DocumentInterface, instance of Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor given

Comment: @seeni : share your export button code...

Comment: <exportButton name="export_button">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="selectProvider" xsi:type="string">product_listing.product_listing.product_columns.ids</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        </exportButton>

Comment: try once with <exportButton name="export_button" />

Comment: Yeah. It has been tried already. Getting the export option in the grid no issues. When click on the export to csv or xml it leads to the issue posted in the previous comment.

Comment: which version you are using?

Comment: Magento EE 2.2.2

Comment: Great !. +1 It is working for me. Thanks